# Polynomial Equation Factoring

Tags: polynomials

Find all polynomials $P(X)$ such that $P(x^2-y^2)=P(x-y)P(x+y)$ for all complex numbers $x$, $y$.

got that P(0)=0 but can't continue

Comment: Hint: Given any $s, t$ there exist $x,y$ such that $s=x-y$ and $t=x+y$. So our condition is equivalent to $P(st)=P(s)P(t)$ for all $s,t$. That should help, a lot.

Comment: [Functional equations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_equation)

Comment: How do you get $p(0)=0$ when the constant polynomial $p(x)=1$ is a solution? It is easy to see that $p(x)\in \{0,1\}$. Set $x=y$ to obtain $p(0)p(2x)=p(0)$ so if $p(0)=1$ then $p(2x)=1$ and you have the constant function. Excluding this $p(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Setting $y=0$, we have $P(x^2)=P^2(x)$.

Let the two leading terms of $P(x)$ be of degree $n$ and $m<n$ respectively. Then the two leading terms of $P(x^2)$ will be of degree $2n$ and $2m$, while those of $P^2(x)$ will be of degree $2n$ and $n+m$.

This mismatch shows that $P(x)$ can only be a power, and its coefficient can only be $1$ to fulfill $a(x^2)^n=(ax^n)^2$.

Besides the trivial $P(x)=0$, any power $P(x)=x^n$ works.

Indeed $$P(x^2-y^2)=(x^2-y^2)^n=(x-y)^n(x+y)^n=P(x-y)P(x+y).$$